# how to create a web service for microsoft graph (C#)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've recently started working as a junior c# developer. My boss asked me to build methods to CRUD teams in our AAD using the microsoft graph API. I've achieved this with a test application like that:

```
public async Task<string> createTeam()
    {
        
        // readying data from registry
        var clientId = "********************"; //application (client) ID
        var clientSecret = "********************"; 
        var redirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"; 
        var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/********************/v2.0"; 

        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                                      .WithAuthority(authority)
                                                      .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                                                      .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                      .Build();


        List<string> scopes = new List<string>
        {
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        };

        //
        var authenticationProvider = new MsalAuthenticationProvider(cca, scopes.ToArray());

        //
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);


        // Code to create a Team


        var team = new Team
        {
            DisplayName = "0000My Sample Team",
            Description = "My Sample Team’s Description",
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
            }
        };

        var result = await graphClient.Teams.Request().AddAsync(team);

        return result.DisplayName;

    }
```

With that piece of code working, I've created an asp.net web Application (.net framework) and added the class to it. The plan was to deploy it to an IIS server and and publish the methods as web services.

```
[WebMethod]
    public async Task<string> createTeamAsync()
    {
        //The class where my methods reside
        TeamServices ts = new TeamServices();

        var result = await ts.createTeam();

        return "OK";
    }
```

I registered the app and deployed but when I try to use it, it does not create any Team.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong of what I should learn next get the app working? Im just a few weeks in c# and I'm completely lost in all that .net echosystem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so, can you include details about that?

Comment: @jefftrotman not, I just access via browser to the web service and invoke it, but it goes silent

Comment: What did you expect it to do? It's just returning a 200/OK - no other stuff here. You will just see a blank page / empty response. Is it also not actually creating the team? Are there web server logs available?

Comment: I expected to create a Team and write in a log if it was succesful or describe which problems happened but neither is done. Maybe graph request couldnt be exposed a web services

Comment: Hi @joan Could you please share the error messages / logs to mitigate the issue.

Comment: Hi @joan, are you still facing the issue, could you please share the error/ log details.