# created a microsoft graph api request, how to make a web service out of it?

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've created this method to create a Team inside an Azure active directory.

```
public async Task CreateTeamTest()
    {
        ...connection stuff...
       
        var team = new Team
        {
            DisplayName = "0000My Sample Team",
            Description = "My Sample Team’s Description",
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
            }
        };

        await graphClient.Teams.Request().AddAsync(team);
    }
```

After that I want to create a service I can call from an app sitting in an IIS, but I aint got a clue how to achieve that, I've started with something like that but it does nothing.

```
[WebMethod]
    public async Task<string> createTeamDePruebaAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            //this is the class containing my method 
            TeamServices ts = new TeamServices();

            await ts.CreateTeamTest();
            return "OK";

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;

        }
               }
```

My question is what route do you people use to transform a method unto a web service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create a web service for microsoft graph (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334334/how-to-create-a-web-service-for-microsoft-graph-c)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is I'm using asmx with a microsoft graph request async, and they dont match

Comment: Is this an answer or speculation?